# How to pass array to controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller, arraylist

I have form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "StoreManager"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
//etc..
}
```

User uploads images to server and when upload is completed immediately thumbnail image is creating and dynamically added to the form in this format:

```
<div class="gridItem">
  <div><img src="image1.jpg"  class="gridThumb" /></div>
  <div class="gridTitle">
  <a href="/Store/del?image1.jpg" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="gridItem">
  <div><img src="image2.jpg"  class="gridThumb" /></div>
  <div class="gridTitle">
  <a href="/Store/del?image2.jpg" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

my question is: how I can get list of all image files from this grid in controller action? 
I want to save this list in model.

Comment: How do you want to send those values to the controller? AJAX? Redirect? POST?

Comment: POST, using standard MVC3 approach @HTML.Form and submit button inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want save the images location and not the binary image itself.

Lets say your controller action looks like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(string[] images)
{
   // do something in images
}
```

I'm not sure how you generate your html, but you could also add a hidden field for each image like this :

```
<input type="hidden" name="images[0]" value="/Store/del?image1.jpg" />
<input type="hidden" name="images[1]" value="/Store/del?image2.jpg" />
```

Then when you post your form, you should receive the array on action parameter.

If you have another requirement, please let me know.

Comment: yes, I need only filenames but not binary content. I.e. src attribute values from img. I add grid items (see 1st message) in uploadify onComplete function 
    //               ...
var content = '<div class="gridItem">' +
                '<div><img id="thumbnailimg" src="' + url + '"  class="gridThumb" /></div>' +
                '<div class="gridTitle"><a href="/StoreManager/DeleteFile?strPath=' +
                fileObj.name
                + '" onclick="return delImg(this);" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></a></div>' +
            '</div>';
$('#thumbnails #mediaGrid').append(content);

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but if you post such an array to the controller action it shoudl work. In onComplete method you could write such input files to the Html with jQuery for exemple.

Comment: Only one note: in some cases it works incorrectly ;-). Example: I added 3 images, and 3 items were added and 3 hidden fields too: images[0], images[1], images[2]. Ok. But if i delete 2nd image (images[1]) then during the Save I see only images[0]... but do not see the images[3], it is not in collection.

Comment: Yes, the condition for MVC Model binder is to have indexes that follow 0 1 2 3 4, etc. You will have to generate on each delete the new hidden fields with following indexes. Otherwise MVC modelbinder stops where there is no next index. Thas why it doesn't see the 3.

Comment: Don't forget to delete other hidden fields before generating the new ones.

Comment: I will ask new question how to do this optimally .. Done, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361083/jquery-how-to-change-each-element-in-grid