# How to change each element in grid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, loops

I have grid like this.
How to change index for each element, i.e. 
to have images[0], images[1], images[2]?

```
<div class="grid">

<div class="gridItem">
  <div><img src="image1.jpg"  class="gridThumb" /></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="images[0]" value="image1.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="gridItem">
  <div><img src="image2.jpg"  class="gridThumb" /></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="images[2]" value="image2.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="gridItem">
  <div><img src="image3.jpg"  class="gridThumb" /></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="images[3]" value="image3.jpg" />
</div>

</div>
```

This is a part of Create view in MVC3 site.
User creates model and uploads files, then he can delete some of them.. and then click Create.
I need to add image names to the model and save this list in db.

```
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create(MyModel m, string[] images)
```

But if user deleted some of items I need to reindex images[i] elements because MVC binding cannot pass array with absent elements.

Comment: It looks like you already do index the elements. I'm sure sure your question is clear.

Comment: Honestly, don't do this.  It's an expensive thing to do that will not scale for a large list.  Either detach and reorder the nodes or rebuild and replace it.  Touching every input seems like a waste of "logic".

Comment: I added details... You wrote "do not do this".. How I can  solve this problem else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
$(function(){
  var gridCnt = 0
  $('.grid').find('.gridItem').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('name','images[' + gridCnt + ']')
    gridCnt++
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=0,$els = $('.gridItem input');

$.each($els,function(){
    $(this).attr('name',"images[" + count + "]");
    count++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.grid .gridItem input').each( function(index, elem){
   elem.attr("name","images["+index+"]");
});
```

Comment: @Pastor Bones : When jQuery each method itself provides index option, why we need another variable gridCnt to store index